# Dominated Convergence Theorem on an integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question**

Let $f:[0,\infty)\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that  $F(t)=\int_{0}^{1} f(t,x) \, dx$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

**Ideas**

It feels like I'll need to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem. A proof would probably have the shape:

Let $(t_n)$ be any sequence in $[0,\infty)$ converging to $t\in [0,\infty)$. Define $f_n(x)=f(t_n,x)$. As $f$ is continuous, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(t,x)$. [Now insert bit about dominating function $g$]. So

$F(t_n)=\int_{0}^{1} f(t_n,x) \, dx\to\int_{0}^{1} f(t,x) \, dx=F(t)$ by DCT. Hence $F$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

But I'm stuck on finding a dominating function since $f$ is general on that domain. Also before we show $F$ is continuous, don't we need to say why it exists in the first place? How do I justify that from the information in the premises?

Thanks

Comment: Since $t_n \to t$, you are considering values of the continuous function $f(t,x)$ for $(t,x)$ in a bounded set $[0,T] \times [0,1]$. Does that ring a bell for you? Also, concerning the existence of $F$, for a given fixed $t$, $f(t,\cdot)$ is continuous function on $[0,1]$ so defining its integral should be OK for you?

Comment: Thanks @cs89 , I understand the second point. For a given $t$, the map $x$ to $f(t,x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, a closed bounded interval, hence the map is itself bounded, so integrable.

Comment: But I do not understand the first part? Could you expand on that please? @cs89

Comment: When you fix a $t \in [0,\infty)$ and take $t_n \to t$, for $n$ large enough, you have $|t_n-t|\leq 1$ say so you could consider the restriction of $f$ to $[0,t+1] \times [0,1]$ which is a compact set. This should help you find a dominating function (or constant).